# Finding for a value in all collections and deleting that value in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have few collections
Collection 1:

```
{
Pid: 111,
Flag: true,
Uploaded: [
    { 
         Name: "abc"
     },
    {
         Name: "def"
     },
    {
         Name: "gig"
     }
]
}
```

Collection2:

```
{
Pid: 113,
Flag: false,
Uploaded: [
    { 
         Name: "abc"
     },
    {
         Name: "hjk "
     },
    {
         Name: "xyz"
     }
]
}
```

Collection3:

```
{
Pid: 114,
Flag: true,
Uploaded: [
    { 
         Name: "money"
     },
    {
         Name: "GUI"
     },
    {
         Name: "abc"
     }
]
}
```

I want to find all the collections having `uploaded.name ="abc"` and wanted to delete only that particular object of uploaded array for that collection.

Output should be:

Collection1:

```
{
Pid: 111,
flag: true,
Uploaded: [
    {
         Name: "def"
     },
    {
         Name: "gig"
     }
]
}
```

Collection2:

```
{
Pid: 113,
Flag: false,
Uploaded: [
    {
         Name: "hjk "
     },
    {
         Name: "xyz"
     }
]
}
```

Collection3:

```
{
Pid: 114,
Flag: true,
Uploaded: [
    { 
         Name: "money"
     },
    {
         Name: "GUI"
     }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use the `$pull` update param

It'll look something like

```
db.myCollection.update({$in: {Uploaded: {Name: "abc"}}}, {$pull: {Uploaded: {Name: "abc"}}}, {multi: true})
```